# Correct usage of subprocess.run() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I would like to run these tree bash commands in Python:

```
sed $'s/\r//' -i filename
sed -i 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d' filename
awk -F, 'NF==10' filename > temp_file && mv temp_file filename
```

I wrote the following code:

```
cmd_1 = ["sed $'s/\r//' -i", file]
cmd_2 = ["sed -i 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d'", file]
cmd_3 = ["awk -F, 'NF==10'", file, "> tmp_file && mv tmp_file", file]

subprocess.run(cmd_1)
subprocess.run(cmd_2)
subprocess.run(cmd_3)
```

But I'm getting this error here:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "sed $'s/\r//' -i": "sed $'s/\r//' -i"
```

What I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide the command as a list, then each argument should be a separate list member. Therefore:

```py
cmd_1 = ["sed" r"s/\r//", "-i", file]
cmd_2 = ["sed" "-i" "s/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d", file]
subprocess.run(cmd_1)
subprocess.run(cmd_2)
```

The last command requires the operators `>` and `&&` provided by the shell, so you will need to also specify `shell=True`, and make the command a string:

```py
cmd_3 = f"awk -F, NF==10 '{file}' > tmp_file && mv temp_file '{file}'"
subprocess.run(cmd_3, shell=True)
```

Comment: I think that I don't need the comma in the cmd_3 definition: cmd_3 = f"awk -F, NF==10 '{file}' > tmp_file && mv tmp_file '{file}'"

Comment: @espogian Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `shell=True` parameter:

```
subprocess.run(cmd_1, shell=True)
```

Comment: I don't think this actually works with `cmd_1` as provided by the OP. When `subprocess.run(..., shell=True)` is given a list as the positional argument, it seems to ignore all list elements after the first one. For example, `subprocess.run(['echo foo', 'bar'], shell=True)` only prints `foo`.